# Implementing an if condition that breaks the while, inside the while condition itself

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have this part of code:

```
int arrayBinary_search(int myarray[], int key){

    int selector;
    int low_limit = 0;
    int high_limit = SIZE;
    while (1){
        selector = (low_limit+high_limit)/2;
        printf("The selector is: %d\n", selector);
        if (myarray[selector] == key){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (low_limit==selector || high_limit==selector)
                break;
            if (key < myarray[selector])
                high_limit = selector;
            else
                low_limit = selector;
            printf("The high_limit is: %d\n", high_limit);
            printf("The low_limit is: %d\n", low_limit);
        }

    }

}
```

This code does a binary search in an array. It works, but `while(1)` is not good to see. I would like to implement some condition to replace that "1" in while. The condition would be that if inside the while cycle, and that breaks it. I tried with: `while (!(low_limit==selector) && !(high_limit==selector))` but it stops after the first cycle, since after the first cycle, "selector" has the same value of "high_limit".

Full code [here](https://hastebin.com/zufoxekufu.cpp).

Comment: Your question seems ok for stackoverflow standards except for the code link, users here are not fond of linked code. The DV's might be caused by that, I would post the code as text instead of a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `do-while` cycle exiting when key maches:

```
int arrayBinary_search(int myarray[], int key)
{
    int selector;
    int low_limit = 0;
    int high_limit = SIZE;

    do {
        selector = (low_limit + high_limit) / 2;
        printf("The selector is: %d\n", selector);

        if (low_limit == selector || high_limit == selector)
            return 0;
        if (key < myarray[selector])
            high_limit = selector;
        else
            low_limit = selector;
        printf("The high_limit is: %d\n", high_limit);
        printf("The low_limit is: %d\n", low_limit);

    } while (myarray[selector] != key);

    return 1;
}
```

On another note, the `arrayGenerator` function does not return an `int` nor you need it to, you sould make it `void`.

Comment: Your code will be always positive. But not always it will find the key. You are not taking in consideration that case since you are returning 1 after the cycle.

Comment: @AllExJ, just `return 0` on `if (low_limit == selector || high_limit == selector)`. I edited the answer.